# executar comando CMD através do JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, cmd

Estou com dificuldades para executar um comando no CMD através do JAVA. Este comando é executado por um .jar que encontra-se dentro de um diretório "C:\CopyUtility\CopyUtility.jar. Por isso preciso entrar neste diretório e executar o comando.

Para isso estou usando a seguinte Servlet abaixo, que recebe os parâmetros a partir de um form em uma página .html. Já fiz o teste e os valores estão sendo enviados corretamente. Creio que o problema está na execução do comando.

```
Public class ExecCopyTestPlanServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //Search Request Parameters
        String strArea = request.getParameter("Area");
        String strID = request.getParameter("ID");
        String strTPID = request.getParameter("TPID");
        String strCommand = "java -jar RQMCopyUtility.jar" + strArea + strID + strTPID;


        Process exec;  
            try {  
                exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C c:\\CopyUtility"+ strCommand);
                if ( exec.waitFor() == 0)  
                    System.out.println("Executado.");  
                else  
                    System.out.println("ERRO");  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

    }
}
```

Nesta linha estou executando o comando:

```
exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C c:\\CopyUtility"+ strCommand);
```

Porém não está funcionando pois o comando não é executado, parece que não está entrando dentro do diretório "C:\CopyUtility".

É preciso abrir o CMD.exe e deixar a janela aberta enquando o comando é executado?

Comment: Está concatenando direto na string sem espaço, mas mesmo assim não faz sentido o comando construído.  Alem do mais, qual a necessidade em invocar o cmd? Não bastaria chamar o java diretamente?  ex:  `java -jar c:\\CopyUtility\\RQMCopyUtility.jar`

Comment: Oi Daniel. Realmente.. interessante esta solução, eu não tinha tentado isso. Vou fazer esta correção e retorno se der certo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: `c:\\CopyUtility` esse "c:" não deveria ser com letra Maiúscula: "C:"?

Comment: Oi Daniel... funcionou. Muito obrigado!!! Atenciosamente,